# Is it true? Adobe AIR based Android development has no future

Tags: android, flash, html, air, adobe

Is it true? Adobe AIR based Android development has no future.
And I heard, Android no longer supports ADOBE AIR/FLASH Systems. Is it True?
And HTML5 Is the best alternate, I heard. Are these points true?

Comment: This question has been asked a lot already, and it really is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I knew, This question doesn't fit here. But I believe ppls in STACKOVERFLOW better understands n guide faster than any other Q&A around the world. I'll avoid this in future!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Not just "Android no longer supports Adobe Flash browser plug-in". Adobe discontinued development of Flash plug-in for browsers on mobile. The point here is that modern web experiences should prioritize mobile and thus I would personally recommend to limit Flash content usage in a web application when it is possible.
2. Adobe AIR applications compile to native applications for both Android and iOS. So you can use it to develop mobile native applications as long as Adobe supports it. If your application is resource intensive or need some access to specific native APIs, there could be certain limitations and thus Java and Objective C might be preferred option depending on platform.
3. HTML5 is completely different story. You cannot build native mobile applications in HTML5 as such. You can build web applications with it. Nevertheless, some tools like PhoneGap can be used to package it as a native application. But there are also certain limitations as with Adobe AIR.

P.S. Unfortunately, there is so much misperception and ignorance with all of that and there are so many people out there who have no clue about the technological aspects, but make categorical statements.

Comment: Phonegap can pack application into a web app. Not native apps. And Adobe AIR 3.0 and above have AIR Native Extensions, which allows code written in native language to be called from AIR. Who needs Flash plugin for mobile? Adobe AIR is the right way to go if choosing the flash platform for development.

Comment: Expanding on: "as long as Adobe supports it". Its important to note that Adobe MUST continue to support AIR on mobile. We can't indefinitely use the last released Air SDK because as it stands every major iOS release will almost certainly break Adobe AIR, requiring Adobe to work on an update. It is my opinion that Adobe doesn't have the motivation to do this more than several more years, and likely will stop support sooner than that.

Comment: There will be continued pressure from developers who invested time and effort into successful apps to keep Adobe AIR updated but at some point Adobe won't want to support it any longer, because too few people "subscribe" to Adobe development tools specifically for the sake of Air applications. I firmly believe that if you are starting out as a new developer, you should not use Adobe Air for Mobile purposes. It is still viable for the veteran Flash developer trying to port their work to mobile (for the time being).

Comment: You can use Native extensions in AIR to overcome any limitations. Also it is one of the cleanest ways to develop cross-plattform applications atm. opposed to html5 wrapper wannabe apps

Answer (score 2):

If Abode AIR has a future or not is of course difficult to say (it's still in its early days compared with the Flash Player), but let's be clear here:

Adobe has "only" discontinued the development of the Flash Player for mobile devices. So basically, **no flash in browsers on mobile**.

It is my understanding Adobe did this so they can **focus on the Flash Player for desktop** and **focus on Adobe AIR**. Let's be honest, the flash player was never going to be supported by iOS, and on Android it was pretty crappy. So I imagine it wasn't a very hard decision to drop the plugin for mobile at this point.

I believe AIR is something Adobe will very much focus on, and according to their [roadmap](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/flash-runtimes-roadmap.pdf) they will try to update the Flash Player and AIR runtime simultaneously in the future, and shift focus for the Flash Player to gaming and premium video.

As been pointed out, AIR can be used to create native apps for iOS and Android, and it's very convenient to develop an app once and then be able to target both platforms, as well as desktop. However, The first time I tried to compile for iOS and Android the performance was horrible (pretty much unusable for gaming). It's gotten a lot better since, but it's still slow compared to an app developed natively with Objective-C for instance. The fact that Adobe will focus on gaming will hopefully result in significantly improved performance for mobile in the future.

Comment: Now i think the decision to discontinue flash plugin support is pretty good: a) apps that are installed are better than go to browser and type also need internet. b) browsers are always slower than native no matter what happens, no amount of optimization can change that at least for a decade with or without flash. c) html5 is no good specs are slow, ie is in its own world, majority still uses older browsers, even newest ones crashes at webgl, and canvas has no hope. So flash would be just another person in a sinking boat.