# Open a file in android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I have a file as3
and button "myButton" in the stage.
And an external file exp "aa.swf"
I want to call up in Android 
it works in my computer but does not open in the Android ... why??help my please""

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.events.Event;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clip1Loaded);
function clip1Loaded(e:Event):void
{

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/sdcard/Download/file/aa.swf");
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    navigateToURL(request,"_blank");
    addChild(loader);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .swf extension is used by files played by Adobe Flash Player. Unfortunately, Flash is not supported on Android since 4.1.

Comment: So what do I do now @prasad thangavel

Comment: We can open a browser or not and how

Comment: this might helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555034/is-it-true-adobe-air-based-android-development-has-no-future